# IphoneX View hidden beside the Tabbar controller's tabbar

Tags: ios, autolayout, iphone-x, safearealayoutguide

I have tabbar controller from one of the tab one view controller is pushed.
in pushed view controller there is view (Camera) which is fixed height and with bottom with safearea.

This view is hidden beside the tabbar in iPhone X but with other device it is correctly visible.

Please suggest solution Thanks in advance

Here is constraint

[image]

in Iphone 6

[image]

in Iphone X See the camera view is hidden

[image]

Comment: check your constraints once.

Comment: @Anbu.karthik I have already checked that . And  in all iphone  camera view is visible  even in iphone 4 but in iphone x only it is hidden beside the tabbar

Comment: @Anbu.karthik I found the issue. Posted as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue by uncheck **under bottom bar** of view controller.

[image]

It is strange that with that checkbox checked issue occurs only in iPhone X device

Hopefully helpful to someone

[image]