# Extend UIViewController's view under tabBar ios

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller, tabbar

I want to extent viewController's view under tabBar.

[image: Image is here]

I tried property of viewController edgesForExtendedLayout = .bottom. But doesn't help

Comment: I think you may have to turn your tabBar to being translucent as well. I tried it from storyboard by changing the Bottom bar - > Translucent Tab Bar and then turning on the option of Extended Edges -> Under bottom bars for a UIViewController.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52287981/iphonex-view-hidden-beside-the-tabbar-controllers-tabbar/52288170#52288170